How can suzanne be scaled relative to the box in geometry nodes?


I need to scale Suzanne relative to boxing. I want to tie Suzanne to boxing so that boxing changes the scale and so does Suzanne.

Assuming the box is axis-aligned like a bounding box, divide the box dimensions by its nominal dimensions, and use that as a scale for the geometry (here: monkey):


